# list index out of range - Python lists with one element

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list with just **one** element as:

```
tempeqpos2 = [600]
```

And it's coordinate is stored in a list called `points3` as follows:

```
points3 = [(1795,3866)]
```

Now I'm trying to append this coordinate into a list called `originalval2` as follows:

```
 originalval2=[]
 for att in tempeqpos2:  
     originalval2.append(list(points3[att]))
```

But this gives me an `IndexError:` `list index out of range`. Can you figure out the problem here?

Since each `tempeqpos2` and `points3` has only one element, I tried making `originalval2` by giving  `originalval2=points3`. But this didn't work...

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Because there is no 600th item in points3. It has only one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey The list `originalval2` should be `[[1795,3866]]`

Comment: You are asking for the item located at index 600 when you do points3[att]. Currently you can only do points3[0]

Comment: @zondo `points3` contains the coordinate of the element `600`.

Comment: So just `originalval2 = [list(points3[0])]`? Or maybe even just `originalval2 = points3.copy()`?

Comment: You might be looking to use a dictionary, not a list. That lets you look up values based on keys you define, so you can tell it that when you look for "600" it gives you something specific.

Comment: @Aran-Fey @Davy M @Gerardo Flores Thanks, everyone! `originalval2 = [list(points3[0])]` worked for me!

Comment: @ccc Glad it worked out! Feel free to accept an answer below!

Comment: also for future reference, if you are erroring and not sure if the function returns what you think it does, then try printing it so you can know what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is when you attempt to access **points3[att]**.

Because **att** resolves to the int **600**, you're asking for **points3[600]** when really only **points3[0]** exists.

Answer (score 1):

i gonna try to explain you the most clear as posible

```
 tempeqpos2 = [600]
 points3 = [(1795,3866)]
 originalval2=[]
 for att in tempeqpos2:  #see that "att" value for the first iteration is 600
 originalval2.append(list(points3[att])) #and here you are asking for the "att"=600 element of the list "points3" that only have 1 element that is (1795,3866)
# and how you know is imposible ask for the element 600 if your list only have 1 element
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `att` is assigned to each item of `tempeqpos2`, which is a list of integers, which in this case, is just `600`, so when `points3[att]` is evaluated, it tries to access the index `600` of the `points3` list, which doesn't exist, since `points3` only has one item.

Since items in `points3` correspond to items in `tempeqpos2`, it's recommended to join them as a dict instead:

```
originalval2 = {}
for i, att in enumerate(tempeqpos2):  
    originalval2[att] = points3[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call point3[att] after for att in tempeqpos2, att is equal to 600. Calling point3[att] is calling position 600 in the list point3.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `index` to get the position of the obj you want.

Example:

```
points3 = [(1795,3866)]
tempeqpos2 = [600]
originalval2=[]
for att in tempeqpos2:
    originalval2.append(list(points3.index(att))
```

`originalval2` would then contain `(1795,3866)`

Or using a dictionary:

```
points3 = [(1795,3866)]
tempeqpos2 = [600]
originalval2={}
for att in tempeqpos2:
    originalval2.append(dict(points3.index(att : tempeqpos2.index(att)))
```

`originalval2` would then contain `600 : (1795,3866)`

Answer (score 0):

Originally what you were trying to do was trying to access the element on the 600th position while there was just one element in the list. You need to access the element on the first position.

```
tempeqpos2 = [600]
points3 = [(1795,3866)]
originalval2=[]
for att in tempeqpos2:  
    originalval2 = points3[0]

print(originalval2)
```

Comment: Fixed, I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing that out. I though all he wanted to do was append

Answer (score 0):

Use of a dictionary might make more sense:

```
tempeqpos2 = [600]
points3 = [(1795,3866)]

originalval2 = {}
for index, att in enumerate(tempeqpos2):  
    originalval2[att] = points3[index]

print(originalval2)
```

Runtime:

```
>>> tempeqpos2 = [600]
>>> points3 = [(1795,3866)]
>>>
>>> originalval2 = {}
>>> for index, att in enumerate(tempeqpos2):
...     originalval2[att] = points3[index]
...
>>> print(originalval2)
{600: (1795, 3866)}
>>>
```

Comment: This is incorrect because you are just assigning the same `points3` to every item in `tempeqpos2`. If `tempeqpos2` had more than one item, your result will be a dict with multiple items of the same value but different keys.

Comment: @blhsing you are correct. I forgot to include an index for tempeqpos2. Edited to reflect that.